# HTML5 FileReader Problems

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, filereader

I am using the Google chrome browser and I run the following code in the console, which seems to work, but when I run it in the script it doesn't

```
reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL($("input[name='image']")[0].files[0]);
alert(reader.result)
somevarname=reader.result
```

The console show the result as a data url, but in the script javascript won't assign the result to the variable and alert is a blank string. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

The FileReader is asynchronous, so in a script the result is set *after*

```
alert(reader.result)
somevarname=reader.result
```

is executed.
You have to use the `onload` property of the FileReader to get the result.
Example:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
//This function will execute when the reader is done
reader.onload = function(){alert(this.result);};
reader.readAsDataURL($("input[name='image']")[0].files[0]);
```

For a good HTML5 File API tutorial, go to [HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).